# Cannot ping two computers with each other on the same switch. (Newbie)

Tags: ip, switch, ipv4, host

I am an absolute 0 in network science and I would like to understand it a little bit.

We have an offline machine connected to a switch, which is also connected to a series of other hardware that control various motors and sensors. In this offline computer you just type on the webbrowser the ip address of such hardware and can already control them.

Because of some home-office rules, we would like to set up a "Gateway" computer, that has 2 ethernet ports and has connection not only with the internet but also with the switch, so we can from home also per remotedesktop have access also to the offline computer.

What I have so far reached is to connect the online machine also to the sensors and motors, but somehow still have not access to the offline computer. Can't even ping between them.

In cmd the command "arp -a" shows everything correctly, even the offline computer's ip address, but still would not work.

Could it be the firewall? How could I test it? Maybe is something with the Switch's IP address? If in the offline computer is blocked the option to access per remote desktop, does it block too the access to its hard drive?

Oh man. Network science is not easy, but I'll get through it :D

Comment: Likely, you'll need to configure the offline machine's firewall to allow RDP - by default, all incoming connection are filtered. Also, RDP is deactivated by default. Pinging might not be allowed by its firewall either but if the MAC address shows up with `arp -a` after `ping` that's not a problem.

Comment: @Zac67 Thank you very much for your response. I gave it a try with Wireshark and even when pinging does not work, the software shows signals going back and forth, so it is very likely that the firewall is the focus point now. I will be telling you if it works!